# Search Central Admin Service not activated

Tags: 2013, search, searchserviceapplication

When I navigate to SharePoint search admin central, I see Errors:

[image]

Comment: Time to look into your ULS logs to see what is struggling. :)

Answer (score 1):

If search status shows as 'All Errors', there can be multiple reasons behind it. You can try following things to see if it helps:

1. Go to Windows services console and restart both SharePoint search service 15/16 and SharePoint search host controller one by one. Wait for sometime to see if helps.
2. Check in Central admin --> Application Management --> Manage Services in Server to see if both services shows as started or not.

   **Note:** Do not perform any start or stop operation from there. Use PowerShell to restart service if it shows as Error or stopped state.
3. Restart the server which is hosting the admin component to see if it helps.
   As part of logs, you can validate in Event logs to see if there are any error message with respect to permissions.

> If nothing helps then recreate search service application to see if
>   that is bringing all components in live state or not.